# Combine multiple sql results into one table?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I'm running a stored procedure using various Select statements. When ran, it outputs each result as it's own table. How can I get these results to show up as just one table?
Below is what the procedure runs:

```
SELECT (SELECT [DailyGoal] FROM [SQL_Testing].[dbo].[packing_goals] WHERE SelCode = 'IMF') as 'DailyGoal',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'IMF' AND Shift = '3' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift3',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'IMF' AND Shift = '1' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift1',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'IMF' AND Shift = '2' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift2',(SELECT [SelCode] FROM [SQL_Testing].[dbo].[packing_goals] WHERE SelCode = 'IMF') as 'SelCode' 
SELECT (SELECT [DailyGoal] FROM [SQL_Testing].[dbo].[packing_goals] WHERE SelCode = 'CRF') as 'DailyGoal',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'CRF' AND Shift = '3' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift3',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'CRF' AND Shift = '1' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift1',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'CRF' AND Shift = '2' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift2',(SELECT [SelCode] FROM [SQL_Testing].[dbo].[packing_goals] WHERE SelCode = 'CRF') as 'SelCode'     
SELECT (SELECT [DailyGoal] FROM [SQL_Testing].[dbo].[packing_goals] WHERE SelCode = 'DNF') as 'DailyGoal',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'DNF' AND Shift = '3' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift3',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'DNF' AND Shift = '1' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift1',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'DNF' AND Shift = '2' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift2',(SELECT [SelCode] FROM [SQL_Testing].[dbo].[packing_goals] WHERE SelCode = 'DNF') as 'SelCode'     
SELECT (SELECT [DailyGoal] FROM [SQL_Testing].[dbo].[packing_goals] WHERE SelCode = 'TBF') as 'DailyGoal',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'TBF' AND Shift = '3' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift3',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'TBF' AND Shift = '1' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift1',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'TBF' AND Shift = '2' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift2',(SELECT [SelCode] FROM [SQL_Testing].[dbo].[packing_goals] WHERE SelCode = 'TBF') as 'SelCode'     
SELECT (SELECT [DailyGoal] FROM [SQL_Testing].[dbo].[packing_goals] WHERE SelCode = 'DIF') as 'DailyGoal',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'DIF' AND Shift = '3' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift3',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'DIF' AND Shift = '1' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift1',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'DIF' AND Shift = '2' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift2',(SELECT [SelCode] FROM [SQL_Testing].[dbo].[packing_goals] WHERE SelCode = 'DIF') as 'SelCode'     
SELECT (SELECT [DailyGoal] FROM [SQL_Testing].[dbo].[packing_goals] WHERE SelCode = 'MSF') as 'DailyGoal',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'MSF' AND Shift = '3' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift3',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'MSF' AND Shift = '1' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift1',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'MSF' AND Shift = '2' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift2',(SELECT [SelCode] FROM [SQL_Testing].[dbo].[packing_goals] WHERE SelCode = 'MSF') as 'SelCode'     
SELECT (SELECT [DailyGoal] FROM [SQL_Testing].[dbo].[packing_goals] WHERE SelCode = 'QBF') as 'DailyGoal',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'QBF' AND Shift = '3' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift3',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'QBF' AND Shift = '1' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift1',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'QBF' AND Shift = '2' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift2',(SELECT [SelCode] FROM [SQL_Testing].[dbo].[packing_goals] WHERE SelCode = 'QBF') as 'SelCode'     
SELECT (SELECT [DailyGoal] FROM [SQL_Testing].[dbo].[packing_goals] WHERE SelCode = 'IPF') as 'DailyGoal',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'IPF' AND Shift = '3' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift3',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'IPF' AND Shift = '1' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift1',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'IPF' AND Shift = '2' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift2',(SELECT [SelCode] FROM [SQL_Testing].[dbo].[packing_goals] WHERE SelCode = 'IPF') as 'SelCode'     
SELECT (SELECT [DailyGoal] FROM [SQL_Testing].[dbo].[packing_goals] WHERE SelCode = 'FSF') as 'DailyGoal',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'FSF' AND Shift = '3' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift3',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'FSF' AND Shift = '1' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift1',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'FSF' AND Shift = '2' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift2',(SELECT [SelCode] FROM [SQL_Testing].[dbo].[packing_goals] WHERE SelCode = 'FSF') as 'SelCode'     
SELECT (SELECT [DailyGoal] FROM [SQL_Testing].[dbo].[packing_goals] WHERE SelCode = 'XTP') as 'DailyGoal',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'XTP' AND Shift = '3' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift3',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'XTP' AND Shift = '1' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift1',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'XTP' AND Shift = '2' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift2',(SELECT [SelCode] FROM [SQL_Testing].[dbo].[packing_goals] WHERE SelCode = 'XTP') as 'SelCode'     
SELECT (SELECT [DailyGoal] FROM [SQL_Testing].[dbo].[packing_goals] WHERE SelCode = 'XTF') as 'DailyGoal',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'XTF' AND Shift = '3' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift3',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'XTF' AND Shift = '1' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift1',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'XTF' AND Shift = '2' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift2',(SELECT [SelCode] FROM [SQL_Testing].[dbo].[packing_goals] WHERE SelCode = 'XTF') as 'SelCode'     
SELECT (SELECT [DailyGoal] FROM [SQL_Testing].[dbo].[packing_goals] WHERE SelCode = 'XWF') as 'DailyGoal',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'XWF' AND Shift = '3' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift3',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'XWF' AND Shift = '1' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift1',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'XWF' AND Shift = '2' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift2',(SELECT [SelCode] FROM [SQL_Testing].[dbo].[packing_goals] WHERE SelCode = 'XWF') as 'SelCode'     
SELECT (SELECT [DailyGoal] FROM [SQL_Testing].[dbo].[packing_goals] WHERE SelCode = 'BTF') as 'DailyGoal',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'BTF' AND Shift = '3' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift3',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'BTF' AND Shift = '1' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift1',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'BTF' AND Shift = '2' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift2',(SELECT [SelCode] FROM [SQL_Testing].[dbo].[packing_goals] WHERE SelCode = 'BTF') as 'SelCode'     
SELECT (SELECT [DailyGoal] FROM [SQL_Testing].[dbo].[packing_goals] WHERE SelCode = 'MPF') as 'DailyGoal',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'MPF' AND Shift = '3' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift3',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'MPF' AND Shift = '1' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift1',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'MPF' AND Shift = '2' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift2',(SELECT [SelCode] FROM [SQL_Testing].[dbo].[packing_goals] WHERE SelCode = 'MPF') as 'SelCode'     
SELECT (SELECT [DailyGoal] FROM [SQL_Testing].[dbo].[packing_goals] WHERE SelCode = 'PNF') as 'DailyGoal',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'PNF' AND Shift = '3' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift3',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'PNF' AND Shift = '1' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift1',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'PNF' AND Shift = '2' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift2',(SELECT [SelCode] FROM [SQL_Testing].[dbo].[packing_goals] WHERE SelCode = 'PNF') as 'SelCode'     
SELECT (SELECT [DailyGoal] FROM [SQL_Testing].[dbo].[packing_goals] WHERE SelCode = 'MCF') as 'DailyGoal',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'MCF' AND Shift = '3' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift3',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'MCF' AND Shift = '1' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift1',(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QtyPacked),0) FROM [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2] WHERE SelCode = 'MCF' AND Shift = '2' AND PackDate = @Date) as 'Shift2',(SELECT [SelCode] FROM [SQL_Testing].[dbo].[packing_goals] WHERE SelCode = 'MCF') as 'SelCode'
```

[Here is an image of the results for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1n1QH.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you guys. I feel so stupid. Ugh. This did the trick.

Comment: You can stick UNION ALL between each statement, but honestly this whole thing should be written.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just...

```sql
select      DailyGoal   = pg.DailyGoal,
            Shift3      = isnull(sum(iif(pa.shift = '3', pa.QtyPacked, 0)), 0),
            Shift1      = isnull(sum(iif(pa.shift = '1', pa.QtyPacked, 0)), 0),
            Shift2      = isnull(sum(iif(pa.shift = '2', pa.QtyPacked, 0)), 0),
            SelCode     = pg.SelCode
from        [SQL_Testing].[dbo].[packing_goals]                   pg 
left join   [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwPackingActivitySnapshotSumQty2]    pa on  pa.selcode = pg.selcode
                                                                     and 
                                                                     (
                                                                        (pa.PackDate = @date and pa.shift in ('1', '3'))
                                                                        or (pa.packDate = @previousDate and pa.shift = '2')
                                                                     )
where       pg.selcode in (
               'IMF', 'CRF', 'DNF', 'TBF', 'DIF', 'MSF', 'QBF', 'IPF', 
               'FSF', 'XTP', 'XTF', 'XWF', 'BTF', 'MPF', 'PNF', 'MCF'
            )
group by    pg.dailygoal,
            pg.selcode
```

Although I admit that without more details on the schema (and the sheer amount of code to read up there) I may have missed something.

Comment: Wow this is awesome! It runs so quick! How would I go about using a different date variable for 2nd shift? (I have 2 date variables @Date and @PreviousDate)

Comment: @alfonso2330 I have updated my answer to handle that new condition.

Comment: once again, thank you! I'm not very good with sql, this is great knowledge to work off!